# sorting a dictionary first by values and then by keys

Tags: python

I have a dictionary in python with string keys and integer values. I want to sort by values and If two values were the same, sort dictionary by keys.
an example of dict. is:

```py
{'Spain':3,'Morocco':1,'England':3,'canada':2}
```

After sorting It should be:

```py
{'England':3,'Spain':3,'canada':2,'Morocco':1}
```

Comment: What did you tried so far?

Comment: d={'Spain':3,'Morocco':1,'England':3,'canada':2}
dic=OrderedDict(sorted(d.items(),key=lambda x: x[::-1],reverse=True))

But we need keys to be in alphabetical order !

Comment: Please [edit] that to the question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try the approach below, which sorts the dictionary by its items.
`-item[1]` sorts by value descending, while `item[0]` sorts by key ascending.
Because the result of sorted is a list of tuples we need to convert it to a dict, using the `dict()` constructor call.

```
d = {'Spain': 3, 'Morocco': 1, 'England': 3, 'canada': 2}
out = dict(sorted(d.items(), key=lambda item: (-item[1], item[0])))
print(out)
```

Output:

```
{'England': 3, 'Spain': 3, 'canada': 2, 'Morocco': 1}
```